# VB.Net Sending errors through mail when error is detected

Tags: vb.net

I'm developing an application with an error log when something goes bad. It must send an e-mail with the error details so I can remotely fix and upload a new update with the fix.

I'm using `Try Catch Exception` but I have a lot of methods to include this option in.

Is there another way to do it without doing so much code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since exceptions bubble up to the application instance try using the [Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms223898.aspx#Y0) Method.

From above MSDN Link:

> It is often not feasible to catch all of the exceptions thrown by
>   Windows Forms. Using this method, you can instruct your application
>   whether it should catch all unhandled exceptions thrown by Windows
>   Forms components and continue operating, or whether it should expose
>   them to the user and halt execution.

```
Public Shared Sub Main()
    ' Add the event handler for handling UI thread exceptions to the event.
    AddHandler Application.ThreadException, AddressOf Form1_UIThreadException

    ' Set the unhandled exception mode to force all Windows Forms errors to go through
    ' our handler.
    Application.SetUnhandledExceptionMode(UnhandledExceptionMode.CatchException)

    ' Add the event handler for handling non-UI thread exceptions to the event. 
    AddHandler AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException, AddressOf CurrentDomain_UnhandledException

    ' Runs the application.
    Application.Run(New Form1()) '' This is your applications Main Form
End Sub

Private Shared Sub Form1_UIThreadException(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal t As ThreadExceptionEventArgs)

'Put Error Handling Code here see the MSDN article for an example implementation

End Sub

Private Shared Sub CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(ByVal sender As Object, _
    ByVal e As UnhandledExceptionEventArgs)

''Put Error Handling Code here see the MSDN article for an example implementation

End Sub
```

Comment: That example doesn't works, ErrorHandlerForm not found... what im doing wrong?

Comment: Did you go to the Link and look at the full code there? It is the event handler for `Application.ThreadException` declared there. Their name is also including the name of the main form

Comment: After researching the link for a while i made it work! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, misunderstood your question. Try putting your logic in a method and just try to call that method in every try catch statement you have.

Example:

```
Public Shared Sub Method1()

    Try
     'Method logic here
    Catch ex As Exception
        EmailError(ex)
    End Try

End Sub

Public Shared Sub EmailError(ex As Exception)

    'your remote error email logic here

End Sub
```